# How to kill process initiated by curl

Tags: php, curl, cron, kill-process

I ran import datafeed using crontab `curl https://...../import.php`. It takes a few hours and in the meanwhile I needed to stop it to debug the script. I ran `ps aux | grep curl` and then I killed PID of curl: `kill -9 24241`. After that this PID is not shown up but import process is still running. I see it in import log file and database records.
How to stop it without reboot?

Comment: Curl is running locally, but the import.php (if on same server) is a different process. So you need to find the PHP PID and kill that as well. It may also spawned as a server process in apache2.

Comment: This is the question. How to find this process? `ps aux | grep import.php` returns nothing

Comment: That's because the webserver is handling this, for example via apache php-fpm.

Comment: A idea could be a .lockfile which regulary check in the php script. If it's gone, the script will stop.